# How to use Java streams to combine child generated lists into a single list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, flatmap

In my code below, I don't like that I have the `List<EmailDraft>` list defined outside of the stream.  I'm pretty sure there is a way to have the stream processing return a `List<EmailDraft>` list directly, I'm just not sure how to do this.  Thoughts?

```
List<EmailDraft> drafts   /* <-- don't like this */
    = new LinkedList<>();

List<SyndFeed> feeds
    = evnt.getFeeds();

feeds.stream().forEach(
    sf -> sf.getEntries().stream().forEach(se -> {

        EmailDraft ed = new EmailDraft();

        // Title
        ed.setTitle(sf.getTitle());

        // ....     

        // Add to list
        drafts.add(ed);  /* <-- don't like this either */
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap` on the feeds and `collect` all the EmailDrafts in a list as following:

```
List<EmailDraft> emailDrafts =
            feeds.stream()
                 .flatMap(
                         sf -> sf.getEntries().stream().map(se -> {

                             EmailDraft ed = new EmailDraft();

                             // Title
                             ed.setTitle(sf.getTitle());

                             return ed;
                         })
                 ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```
feeds.stream().flatmap(
    sf -> sf.getEntries().stream()).map(se -> {

        EmailDraft ed = new EmailDraft();

        // Title
        ed.setTitle(sf.getTitle());

        // ....     

        return ed;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using range to create stream of `title` repeated for the number of elements in `sf.getEntries()`:

```
        List<EmailDraft> drafts = feeds.stream()
        .flatMap( sf -> IntStream.range( 0, sf.getEntries().size() ).mapToObj( i -> sf.getTitle() ) )
        .map( t -> { 
                       EmailDraft ed = new EmailDraft(); 
                       ed.setTitle(t); 
                       return ed;
                    } 
        )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overcomplicating things and doing everything with streams, you just could do it the *old* pre Java-8 way:

```
List<EmailDraft> drafts = new ArrayList<>();
for(SyndFeed sf : feeds){
    for(int i = sf.getEntries().size(); i > 0; i--){
        EmailDraft ed = new EmailDraft();
        ed.setTitle(sf.getTitle());
        drafts.add(ed);
    }
}
```

which IMO should be preferred because it is such a simple task.